# Can I use Desktop's DVD writer on laptop via sata data connection, powering it with SMPS externally

Tags: laptop, power-supply, sata, dvd, desktop

Can I use Desktop's DVD writer on laptop via sata data connection, powering it with SMPS externally (SMPS of desktop)?

I mean power supply to Desktop's DVD writer will be done though Desktop's SMPS and Sata data cable will be connected to laptop's sata connectors (Temporarily replacing harddisk's sata data connector).

This is a work around I'm thinking of to flash the Laptop's BIOS with through CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

No reason why this wouldn't work, but you will need a very long sata cable. Far easier to buy a USB cd drive as these are very cheap and far more convenient, being powered from the USB cable.

Comment: Yeah long SATA data cable is necessary. Desktop has spare SATA data connector cables, will borrow one from desktop itself. Yeah USB  DVD writers are available to buy but I'm thinking of something that is in hand or ready now . This is just as  a work around for now. Thank you very much for help! :)

Comment: I forgot I cannot borrow sata data cable from desktop because yeah sata data cable's other end (that connects to laptop) is different (uses different pin approach to connect to laptop). something like the one here https://www.xfurbish.com/laptop-hdd-connector-for-hp-m1-v001dx-122inml464u-refurbished?gclid=CjwKCAjw0qOIBhBhEiwAyvVcf7TngGc3EIdB75H9qElejMH9_qXyLq3zar7O7FpgEi-V5v57n1x-yxoCTMsQAvD_BwE

Comment: USB is the way to go! 6GBP! https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/133808549432